# Is it possible to upload an image in firebase storage through a Cypress test in GitHub Actions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cypress, firebase-storage, github-actions

I am trying to add a file (jpeg file) into the firebase storage in a Cypress e2e test. It runs fine and the test case passes locally. I login the user, perform all the required actions (clicking button, attach file from fixtures folder to the input tag for file, save changes by clicking button).
But issue occurs in Github actions CI/CD pipeline, All the testcases pass but error occurs on this test case that **Cannot read properties of undefined (Reading name)**. I am accessing fileselected.name when changes are saved.
My assumption is that the file is not found by cypress or there is an issue related to permissions in firebase storage that is why it is failing. Can anybody help/guide me about why is it not working?

My Cypress test:

```
it("adds company successfully", () => {
    cy.visit("http://127.0.0.1:3000/dashboard/company", {
      headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate" },
    }).then(() => {
      cy.wait(10000);
      cy.get("#newCompany").click();
      cy.get("#companyName").type("Test company").blur();
      cy.get("#companyEmail").type("testCompany@gmail.com").blur();

      cy.get("input[type=file]").selectFile(
        {
          contents: "cypress/fixtures/file.jpeg",
          fileName: `file${new Date().toISOString()}.jpeg`,
        },
        {
          force: true,
        }
      );

      cy.get(".purple-button").contains("Save Changes").click();
    });
  });
```

The handleSave() function runs on clicking Save Changes button.

```
const handleSave = () => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    if (isFormValid()) {
      if (fileSelected.name) {
        handleUpload();
      } else {
        saveCompany(companyPictureUrl);
        props.handleClose();
      }
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    try {
      setIsUploading(true);
      const storageRef = ref(storage, "company/" + fileSelected.name);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fileSelected);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot: { bytesTransferred: number; totalBytes: number }) => {
          const progress =
            Math.round(
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 1000
            ) / 10;
          setUploadProgress(progress);
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        async () => {
          try {
            const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
            setCompanyPictureUrl(url);
            saveCompany(url);
            props.handleClose();
          } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log("Error while uploading file :: ", ex);
    }
  };`
```

Github actions error:
[image]

Comment: Look like there is an error in your application code. Could u share the `/dashboard/company` code? or at least the line where you call that `.name`

Comment: I have edited the question with the code @ToniBardinaComas

Comment: i would need to at least see where `fileSelected` is set